# Azure Data Factory alert giving wrong UTC date

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, azureportal

I currently have an Azure Data Factory resource and am configuring an alert to trigger when a pipeline runs longer than 120 minutes. It partially works however, sometimes I get a strange date in return:

[image]

Does anyone know what this date means or if it's just invalid?

Answer (score 0):

End date might get updated after the pipeline finishes or stops. You have created alert for in progress pipelines I believe.